# How do I get position and x/y/z axis out of a LH 4x4 world matrix?

Tags: math, matrix, direct3d

As far as I know, Direct3D works with an LH coordinate system right?

So how would I get position and x/y/z axis (local orientation axis) out of a LH 4x4 (world) matrix?

Thanks.

*In case you don't know: LH stands for left-handed*

Comment: What does LH stand for? Does the last row of the 4x4 matrix look like (0,0,0,1)? If so, it probably is an element of SE(3), the special Euclidian group. I can definitely help you with that.

Comment: @VladSeghete LH means left-handed

Comment: Oh, ok. I don't think left-handed versus right handed is a problem unless you try to switch between the two representations. As long as all your coordinate systems are left-handed what I suggested below will work. If you want to have some parts of your code represent things right-handed for any reason then you need to make sure you transform between the two representations correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If the 4x4 matrix is what I think it is (a homogeneous rigid body transformation matrix, same as an element of SE(3)) then it should be fairly easy to get what you want. Any rigid body transformation can be represented by a 4x4 matrix of the form

```
g_ab = [ R, p;
         0, 1]
```

in block matrix notation. The `ab` subscript denotes that the transformation will take the coordinates of a point represented in frame `b` and will tell you what the coordinates are as represented in frame `a`. `R` here is a 3x3 rotation matrix and `p` is a vector that, when the rotation matrix is unity (no rotation) tells you the coordinates of the origin of `b` in frame `a`. Usually, however, a rotation is present, so you have to do as below.

The position of the coordinate system described by the matrix will be given by applying the transformation to the point (0,0,0). This will well you what world coordinates the point is located at. The trick is that, when dealing with SE(3), you have to add a 1 at the end of points and a 0 at the end of vectors, which makes them vectors of length 4 instead of length 3, and hence operable on by the matrix! So, to transform point (0,0,0) in your local coordinate frame to the world frame, you'd right multiply your matrix (let's call it g_SA) by the vector (0,0,0,1). To get the world coordinates of a *vector* (x,y,z) you multiply the matrix by (x,y,z,0). You can think of that as being because vectors are differences of points, so the 1 in the last element goes the away. So, for example, to find the representation of your local x-axis in the world coordinates, you multiply g_SA*(1,0,0,0). To find the y-axis you do g_SA*(0,1,0,0), and so on.

The best place I've seen this discussed (and where I learned it from) is [A Mathematical Introduction to Robotic Manipulation by Murray, Li and Sastry](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/%7Emurray/books/MLS/pdf/mls94-complete.pdf) and the chapter you are interested in is 2.3.1.

Comment: What do you mean with SE(3)
I'm also not really sure what you're stating here. Could you give some code examples?

I have read somewhere what the specific elements of the matrix represent, and it showed me which combination of elements made up the local axis, and which elements made up the position of an element. I didn't have to multiply anything.

Also, I think LH matters because LH matrices are organised differently than RH matrices (row-major / column-major or something)

Comment: I added a (very) short explanation of homogeneous coordinates. The link in my post and Google have a lot more details. As far as LH vs. RH goes, the only thing that changes is the direction you measure angles. With a RH system you use the right hand rule, and angles are positive in the counterclockwise direction. With a LH system it is the opposite. The math is identical when you stay in one or the other (it is purely a matter of convention).